# When planning a trajectory, why is there never an initial in-place rotation?

Tags: ros, navigation, base-global-planner, move-base, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe this is a result of my configuration choices, but why does the planner never do an initial in-place rotation?  It is happy to do an in-place rotation at the end of a move.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233722/when-planning-a-trajectory,-why-is-there-never-an-initial-in-place-rotation?/) by [mitch](https://answers.ros.org/users/22960/mitch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-05-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I discovered that it will do an initial in-place rotation toward the planned path if you set this base_local_planner parameter:
**heading_scoring: true**

You may also want to set heading_scoring_timestep, perhaps to match the value that you set sim_time to. Its default of 0.1 seconds did not work well for us.

Before discovering this parameter, we had implemented a custom node to sit between the output of the nav stack and /cmd_vel which would force an initial in-place rotation, but now we no longer need that.

---

Originally posted by [howardcochran](https://answers.ros.org/users/28150/howardcochran/) with karma: 76 on 2016-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1